# Building combined interface array

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm looking way to build LDAP style (objectclass) array interface structure.
I have tried multiple ways with different variations of interfaces, but rough base idea is something like this ...

```
export enum ObjectClassEnum {
    top = 'top',
    posixGroup = 'posixGroup',
    groupOfNames = 'groupOfNames',
}

export interface ILdapObject {
    objectClass: ObjectClassEnum[];
}

export interface ILdapObjectTop extends ILdapObject {
    objectClass: ObjectClassEnum.top[];
}

export interface ILdapObjectPosixGroup extends ILdapObject {
    objectClass: Array<ObjectClassEnum.top | ObjectClassEnum.posixGroup>;
}

export interface ILdapObjectGroupOfNames extends ILdapObject {
    objectClass: Array<ObjectClassEnum.top | ObjectClassEnum.groupOfNames>;
}
```

And object ...

```
const test: ILdapObjectPosixGroup & ILdapObjectGroupOfNames  =  {
    objectClass: [ObjectClassEnum.top, ObjectClassEnum.groupOfNames, ObjectClassEnum.posixGroup],
}
```

Idea is that object should combine now features from both interfaces, but fails as both don't share same actual objectClasses in interfaces ...

Edit: I think actually this is issue what I'm facing here ...
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16936

Comment: could you please provide some expected usage examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note is that when you write `[SomeType]` that means a tuple of exactly one element of that type, if you want an array, that should be `SomeType[]`.

Another thing is that parent interface should be *more general* than the child one, which is opposite in your code.

Depending on your requirements something like this should work:

```
export enum ObjectClassEnum {
    top = 'top',
    posixGroup = 'posixGroup',
}

export interface ILdapObject {
    objectClass: ObjectClassEnum[]; 
}

export interface ILdapObjectTop extends ILdapObject {
    objectClass: ObjectClassEnum.top[]; 
}

export interface ILdapObjectPosixGroup extends ILdapObject {
    objectClass: (ObjectClassEnum.top | ObjectClassEnum.posixGroup)[]; 
}

const test: ILdapObjectPosixGroup = {
    objectClass: [ObjectClassEnum.top, ObjectClassEnum.posixGroup],
}

function processObject(obj: ILdapObject) {
    // ...
}

processObject(test)
```

Comment: I'm happy to help. Whenever your question is answered on StackOverflow please also accept the relevant answer so the system marks question as resolved.

Comment: If I create two interfaces from ILdapObject (i.e. posixGroup and groupOfNames) it seems that I can't combine those as another does not have required objectClasses compared to other ... maybe I try to build this as too complex setup. Basically it should be like objectClass in interface must contain those Enums keys, but still can contain other ObjectClassEnum's.

Comment: Please add in info in the original question on what is not working and I can take a look